# requestFeature() must be called before adding content exception

Tags: java, android, layout

I've seen lots of people asking about this and usually the answer has been something along the lines of: "Do it before

> setContentView(R.layout.test_layout);

or

> Do it before super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

I've tried them both, but putting it before
    setContentView(R.layout.test_layout); 
gives the exception, where as putting it before:
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
doesn't give an exception, but it doesn't work either...

I got the fullscreen working by putting:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`
```

before

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

I've seen plenty of other ways to force noTitleScreen and fullscreen, but none of them seemed to work. (No errors on most of the other ways, they just didn't seem to do anything) Like changing the layout theme... Did nothing for some reason.

I'm using Android Studio.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is the whole activity. I feel the need to defend myself by saying this is my first time developing with java, so excuse me if I have any obvious mistakes here :3 ->

```
package the1n07.bt_rc;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.gesture.Gesture;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;


public class ControlActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button speedPlusButton, speedMinusButton, forwardButton, backwardButton, leftButton, rightButton;
    EditText speedText;

    public String speed;
    public Integer speedInt;
    public boolean forward = false, backward = false, left = false, right = false;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//have tried putting the line here
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
//and here
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//and here
        setContentView(R.layout.test_layout);
//and even here just in case, though I'm pretty sure it's not supposed to go here

        Main();

    }

    public void Main(){
        speedPlusButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.speedPlusButton);
        speedMinusButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.speedMinusButton);
        speedText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.speedText);
        forwardButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.forwardButton);
        backwardButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backwardButton);
        leftButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.leftButton);
        rightButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rightButton);



        speedPlusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                speed = speedText.getText().toString();
                speedInt = Integer.parseInt(speed);

                if(speedInt != 5) {
                    speedInt = speedInt + 1;
                }
                speed = Integer.toString(speedInt);
                speedText.setText(speed);
            }
        });

        speedMinusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                speed = speedText.getText().toString();
                speedInt = Integer.parseInt(speed);

                if(speedInt != 1) {
                    speedInt = speedInt - 1;
                }
                speed = Integer.toString(speedInt);
                speedText.setText(speed);
            }
        });

        forwardButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                switch (event.getAction())
                {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        forward = true;
                        forwardButton.setBackgroundColor(0xFF7D7D7D);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        forward = false;
                        forwardButton.setBackgroundColor(0xff222222);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                        forwardButton.setBackgroundColor(0xff222222);
                        forward = false;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

        backwardButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                switch (event.getAction())
                {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        backward = true;
                        backwardButton.setBackgroundColor(0xFFB9B9B9);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        backward = false;
                        backwardButton.setBackgroundColor(0xffffffff);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                        backwardButton.setBackgroundColor(0xffffffff);
                        backward = false;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

        leftButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                switch (event.getAction())
                {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        left = true;
                        leftButton.setBackgroundColor(0xFF7D7D7D);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        left = false;
                        leftButton.setBackgroundColor(0xff222222);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                        leftButton.setBackgroundColor(0xff222222);
                        left = false;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

        rightButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                switch (event.getAction())
                {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        right = true;
                        rightButton.setBackgroundColor(0xFFB9B9B9);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        right = false;
                        rightButton.setBackgroundColor(0xffffffff);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                        rightButton.setBackgroundColor(0xffffffff);
                        right = false;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: show your activity code.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that. didn't work. I have forced a landscape view if that makes a difference? Also, just to make sure: title bar is the one with the Activity name on it right? :/